# How iterate through text and replace a specific words

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, string-matching

I'm trying to write a simple function that iterates through text and replaces any href's it comes across with text instead;

```
var REPLACE = [
    {expression: www.anyhref.com, value: 'website'}
];

function(instance) {
   instance = function {
       var insteadURL;

       insteadURL: = REPLACE.match(function(expression) {
           return element.classList.contains(expression);
       });

       return(
           insteadURL ? insteadURL.value : getElementText(expression)
       );
   }
}
```

I feel as though I may not be using the match method or the conditional operator properly but from what I understand this should work. But of course it doesn't.

Comment: There is a typo in the second insteadURL.

Comment: Is your problem with `match` method, or you're seeking a regex etc. to match urls/hrefs?

Comment: Actually `REPLACE.match` will throw an error because `REPLACE` is an `array` and not a `string`.

Comment: @vahdet are you possibly able to provide an example for some guidance?

Comment: I am trying to understand the very exact point where you're stuck, in short. Hence, I first have to understand your pinpoint concern, and then try to come up with a solution.

Comment: I suggest you add input and output data to this T.Doe, so that readers may replicate the problem on their own machines. Readers generally need a [mcve] to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to replace links (i guess) in your text, try this regex:

```
   /<a.*?href="www.anyhref.com".*?\/a>/g
```

Then you would have to add for each href you want to replace an entry in your array.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in DOM context you can do the following:

To iterate through the DOM you can use this function:

```
function domReplace(node, iterator) {
  switch (node && node.nodeType) {
  case 1: case 9: case 11: {
    const newNode = iterator((node.nodeName || '').toLowerCase(), node);
    if (newNode && newNode != node && node.parentNode) {
        node.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, node);
        node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
    }
    for (let child = newNode.firstChild; child; child = child.nextSibling)
       domReplace(child, iterator);
  } break ;
  case 3: {
    const newNode = iterator('#text', node);
    if (newNode && newNode != node && node.parentNode) {
        node.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, node);
        node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
    }
  } break ;
  }
}
```

Then you can replace `a` if pattern matches `.href` with custom text:

```
domReplace(document, (type, node) => {
  if (type == 'a') {
    for (let i = 0; i < REPLACE.length; i += 1)
      if (~(node.href || '').indexOf(REPLACE[i].expression))
         return document.createTextNode(REPLACE[i].value);
    return document.createTextNode(node.href);
  }
  return node;
});
```

Note you should not give `document` to `domReplace` but the right dom node to avoid full page replacement